# Android: AccessibilityNodeInfo.performAction() is not working on DialPad and keyboard

Tags: android

I have this application that performs click on Android apps from backend service.
In the AccessibilityService, the following code works fine to click anywhere on the screen (on any app).

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo node = null;
...
...
node.performAction(action.getId());
```

But is does not work for Soft Keyboard and DialPad. what is the reason? Is it a security reason? How can I overcome it?

Thanks!

Comment: Wondering if you were able to solve it somehow?

Comment: As i recall, i couldnt solve it. Security reasons.